# How to pass text area values from one page to another in PHP

Tags: php, post, textarea

I have a page `page1.php` (lets say) and there are some text area boxes on this page like -

```
<form name="viewRun" action="/auto/page2.php" method="post">
    <td><textarea name="qatxt1 " rows="2" cols="20"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name="autotxt1 " rows="2" cols="20"></textarea></td>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value='Submit' style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
```

Now, users fills the text area boxes on page1.php and clicks `Submit` button and page2.php is loaded. The problem is that I am unable to retrieve the comments that user put in these text area boxes on page2. php. I have the following code on page2.php -

```
<?php 
$varTemp= $_POST["qatxt1 "];
?>
```

`$varTemp` is just blank.

Your help is highly appreciated as always !!

Comment: First of all, you can remove the `?` from your action URL. It's unnecessary. Secondly, what does `var_dump($_POST)` produce for you?

Comment: I know the HTML is just an example, but you can't have `<td>`s inside of `<form>` like that.

Comment: To expand upon @Rocket's comment, don't use tables if you're not displaying tabular data. It's TERRIBLE practice. Instead, use CSS (Cascading Style Sheets).

Comment: @Rocket, Matt - `var_dump($_POST)` returns `array(21) { ["qatxt1 "]=> string(0) ""` . Actually, Page1.php displays some data from a table and then I am adding two text area columns. I need to fire an update query to update the comments in the text area. That is why you see <TD> element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have spaces in names.

```
<textarea name="qatxt1 " rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Should be:

```
<textarea name="qatxt1" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Then you can read it like:

```
$varTemp = $_POST["qatxt1"];
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").